# Add a button link to a div in HTML

Tags: html

I have a HTML div like,

```
<div id="tab2" class="tab">
    <div class="alarm" id="alarm">
      <img src="src/alarm.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-size: contain;">
     </div>
 </div>
```

So I want to open this div when a button click. I tried to add a link to the button like this way,

```
<a href="#tab2" class="button">Get Start</a>
```

But this is not working. How can I do this. Please help me !

Comment: I think you should look at jQuery or something similar. To show the div you need to run javascript to change the CSS visibility of the div.

Comment: If you are using bootstrap, you could use collapse: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML Code:

```
<div id="tab2" class="tab" style="display:none;">
    <div class="alarm" id="alarm">
      <img src="src/alarm.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-size: contain;">
     </div>
 </div>

<a href="#tab2" class="button" onclick="showDiv()">Get Start</a>
```

Javascript:

```
function showDiv() {
   document.getElementById('tab2').style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this with javascript

```html
<div id="tab2" class="tab" style="display: none;">
  <div class="alarm" id="alarm">
    <img src="src/alarm.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-size: contain;">
  </div>
</div>

<a href="#tab2" class="button" id="button1">Get Start</a>

<script>
  document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("tab2").style.display = "block"
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this css and try :

```
 #tab2{
   display:none;
  }

 #tab2:target{
   display:block;
  }
```